# php header download - Cannot open file: it does not appear to be a valid archive

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

File downloads are working - except for larger file downloads - the big file downloads too quickly and is corrupted when opened - I get the error message (for zip files): Cannot open file: it does not appear to be a valid archive. The file is def uploading ok and is in the folder

This is the php code I am using to force a header download

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: Do you get an error? E.g. abuot max file size or time?

Comment: no - cant see any errors

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: Do the function filesize return correct on larger files?

Comment: on larger files - function filesize does not return the file size at all

Comment: I also have error reporting enabled but cant see any errors

Comment: Check the downloaded file and see how long it is. 0 bytes? Something blew up on the server, but silently. Only a few hundred bytes - open it in a text editor and see if something output an error message then blew up. As well, check that `$file` is pointing at the right spot. If not, you'll get no-such-file warning messages

Comment: I opened one of the files in a text editor and get this ‹. - the file size if 4kb

Answer (score 0):

First try to access the file directly(direct URL to the zip file).

If it also gives a error or corrupted use a thing like 
stream writer to write chunk of data at a time.

(assume server side file is not corrupted)

OR use thing like this

http://php.net/manual/en/httpresponse.send.php

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

It was a Maximum memory allocation problem - it had a php default setting of 236M

I upped this and its working

appreciate all the help

Regards

Jeff

Comment: Just raising the memory allocation  limit is a bad idea. This means that the whole file will be read into memory when someone tries to download it which can create quite a performance hit on the server. Look at this thread how you can read the file in chunks instead to only keep a small part of it in memory at any time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647329/php-download-jpg-or-avi/11647520#11647520

Answer (score 0):

Even by upping the memory allocation the downloads were still pretty unreliable. I Managed to get it stable by using the below. Appreciate everyones input.

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

$fp = fopen($file, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
echo fread($fp, 65536);
flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
} 
fclose($fp);
```