# PHP download .jpg or .avi

Tags: php, file, download

I have gotten a problem about downloading .jpg and .avi files from a server using PHP
I have the following code:

```
$fileName = "Koala.jpg";
$filePath = "./Koala.jpg";
if (!file_exists($filePath)){
    echo "No file";
    return;
}
$fp = fopen($filePath, "r");
$fileSize = filesize($filePath);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Content-Length: $fileSize");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".$fileName);

$buffer = 1024;
while(!feof($fp)){
    $data = fread($fp, $fileSize);
    echo $data;
}
fclose($fp);
```

The code downloads .txt file successfully and the downloaded file can be read.
However, when it comes to .jpg, the downloaded .jpg file cannot be read.
Can anyone give a helping hand? Thanks

Have just tried another method and it works fine

```
$file = 'Koala.jpg';

if (file_exists($file)) {
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
```

But just wonder what reason causes the first method fail, even though using fopen("xxx", "rb") instead. Thank you

Comment: What's the specific error you're getting?

Comment: the error said the file may be damaged.

Comment: Thanks all. The problem may be due to the output buffer. The problem is solved after adding ob_clean to erase the output buffer before echoing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing application/octet-stream for  image/jpeg .

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm no php expert (sorry to say) but I remember having a similar problem when using php on a Windows server. It stemmed from opening the file without the binary-flag (should be `fopen($filePath, "rb");` in your sample). If you don't set that flag your data might be altered when you read it from the stream which could break your files (and you wouldn't notice it on textfiles).

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php for more info on the different modes available.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this --

```
<?php
$filename = "MyImage.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the following code that you are using,

```
$buffer = 1024;
while(!feof($fp)){
    $data = fread($fp, $fileSize);
    echo $data;
}
```

Just use `readfile` method

```
readfile($filePath);
```